# Can not compile Erlang file using file module

Tags: file, erlang

When I want to compile a simple `file.erl` file, I got the error message.

```
$ erlc file.erl
/opt/erlang17.5/lib/kernel-3.2/include/file.hrl:34: type date_time() undefined
```

Below is the content of file.erl

```
-module(file).
-include_lib("kernel/include/file.hrl").

-export([file_info/1]).

file_info(Dir) ->
    {ok, F} = file:read_file_info(Dir),
    io:format("~p~n", [F#file_info.type]).
```

It seems nobody reported this kind of issue, is there anything wrong with what I did?

Comment: I'm not sure why you get this kind of error but `file.erl` already exists in kernel sources so changing module name should help.

Comment: @ŁukaszPtaszyński thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right, the problem is with filename. Erlang has library "file", so you cannot use this filename. Change it (don't forget to modify source) and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

It's instructive to investigate the root cause of the compilation problem. The compiler emits this error:

> /opt/erlang17.5/lib/kernel-3.2/include/file.hrl:34: type date_time() undefined

Looking at line 34 of `file.hrl` we see:

```
ctime  :: file:date_time() | non_neg_integer(),
```

This is a type specifier for the `ctime` field of the `#file_info{}` record. It states that `ctime` can hold a value of either the `file:date_time()` type or of the `non_neg_integer()` type.

The error message complains specifically about the `date_time()` type because its scope indicates that it's defined in the `file` module. In this case, the `file` module is the one being defined and compiled, and it's hiding the standard one provided by the Erlang/OTP `kernel` application. The standard `file` module defines its `date_time()` type as follows:

```
-type date_time() :: calendar:datetime().
```

The `file` module we're trying to compile, though, does not. What happens if we add this type definition?

```
-module(file).
-type date_time() :: calendar:datetime().
-include_lib("kernel/include/file.hrl").

-export([file_info/1]).

file_info(Dir) ->
    {ok, F} = file:read_file_info(Dir),
    io:format("~p~n", [F#file_info.type]).
```

Compiling this version containing the added type definition now works:

```
$ erlc file.erl
$
```

We've fixed the compilation error, so let's try to use our compiled module. We start an Erlang shell:

```
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{file,path_eval,[[".","/Users/user"],".erlang"],[]},{c,f_p_e,2,[{file,"c.erl"},{line,481}]},{init,eval_script,8,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

We can see in the error message that an attempt to call `file:path_eval/2` failed because it's not defined. Because our `file` module hides the standard one but doesn't supply all the same functions, we can't even start up an Erlang shell as long as our `file` module hides the standard one.

Clearly, choosing a different name for the module is necessary for more than just fixing the original compilation error.